# How to fix mocha test on a route?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai-http

I have a route, I am performing a mocha test on that route. the test fails with the error message
Uncaught AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 201'

I have gone over the test case and everything seems to be fine. anyone with an idea what might be wrong

#### test

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import app from '../src/app';
import vehicles from '../src/db/carDb';

const { expect } = chai;
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Car', () => {
  it('should create new car in app', (done) => {
    const car = {
      state: 'used',
      status: 'available',
      price: 2000000,
      manufacturer: 'toyota',
      model: 'camry',
      bodyType: 'car',
    };
    chai.request(app)
      .post('/api/v1/car')
      .send(car)
      .end((err, res) => {
        const { body } = res;
        if (err) done(err);
        expect(res).to.be.an('object');
        expect(body.status).to.equal(201);
        expect(res.body.message).to.be.equal('Vehicle created successfully');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

#### controller

```
static createCar(req, res) {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateNewCar(req.body);
    if (!isValid) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }
    const vehicle = {
      id: vehicles.length + 1,
      userId: 3,
      state: req.body.state,
      status: 'available',
      price: req.body.price,
      manufacturer: req.body.manufacturer,
      model: req.body.model,
      bodyType: req.body.bodyType
    };

    vehicles.push(vehicle);
    return res.status(201).json({
      status: 201,
      message: 'Vehicle created successfully',
      data: vehicle,
    });
  }
```

I expect the test to pass but the app returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

```js
expect(body.status).to.equal(201);
```

Your error says `body.status` is `undefined`.

If you have a look at `chai-http`'s [documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/) and look for `status`, you'll see they use a specifically-designed syntax:

```js
expect(res).to.have.status(201);
```

However, you can probably (didn't test it) reach the status code as a [standard](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode) `http.ServerResponse` instance, which would not be in the body, instead it'd be:

```js
expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(201);
```

Comment: Tried this, get a 500 error. This only happens when I add validation to the controller

Comment: @Dolapo 500, like the server crashes because you altered its test? Seems weird - unrelated? - to me!